# How to wrap first element and then every n?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have a number of images and I need to wrap them two and two together inside of a div except for the first image. That one needs to be wrapped separately.

This is what I'm currently doing but I can't figure out how to wrap the first element also.

```
    $(function(){
    var c = $('#reader').children();

    for (var i = 1 ; i < c.length ; i+=2) {
        c.slice(i,i+2).wrapAll('<article class="row"></article>');
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(function () {
    var c = $('#reader').children();

    //first child
    c.eq(0).wrap('<article class="row"></article>');
    for (var i = 1; i < c.length; i += 2) {
        c.slice(i, i + 2).wrapAll('<article class="row"></article>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($(".new-grid__item:eq(0), .new-grid__item:eq(1)")){

   $(".new-grid__item:eq(0), .new-grid__item:eq(1)").wrapAll('<div class="child"></div>');
  }
  if($(".new-grid__item:gt(1)")){

  $(".new-grid__item:gt(1)").wrapAll('<div class="child"></div>');
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey there! Your answer's quality would increase greatly if you could add an explanation by clicking [edit] to edit your answer :)